# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^{1/n}-1$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/n!)^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^{1/n}-1$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/n!)^{1/n}$$

Hi. I am working on calculus now. While studying convergence test part, I ran into those problems... Wolfram alpha says they both diverges by comparison test. But I cannot think of the series to apply the comparison test... I tried $\sum 1/n$ or $\sum 1/n^2$ but failed..... Can you give me any clue?? I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{1}{n!} \geq \dfrac{1}{n^n}$ and this proves the second series diverges by comparison to the harmonic series. The first one is already asked here, and I just quoted its proof: $\sqrt[n]{n} - 1 \geq c\dfrac{\ln n}{n}, c > 0$ and this means it diverges by comparison test as well since the right series diverges by again comparing it to the harmonic series.